# The html menu collapses but does not move to the specified id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have a jquery code which moves "a" element after clicking on the link to the given id given in the link in href.

HTML code snippet:

```
<nav class="navbar w-100 align-items-center navbar-expand-md fixed-top bg-white border-bottom shadow-sm">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="my-0 mr-md-auto logo">
            <a href="index.html">
                <img src="images/apietrzak-color.svg" width="200px" alt="Apietrzak.pl">
            </a>
        </div>
        <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu_apietrzak">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="ml-lg-5 pl-lg-5 pl-xs-0 ml-xs-0 collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" id="menu_apietrzak">
            <ul class="pl-lg-4 navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <a class="p-2 mbold blue" href="#glowna">Home</a>
                <a class="p-2 mbold blue" href="#o-nas">O nas</a>
                <a class="p-2 mbold blue" href="#oferta">Oferta</a>
                <!--<a class="p-2 mbold blue" href="#galeria" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Galeria</a>-->
                <a class="p-2 mbold blue" href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a>
            </ul>
            <a class="ml-5 phone blue navbar-right dnone" href="tel:500192282">tel. +48 500 192 282</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

My JQUERY CODE:
(jquery-3.4.1.min.js)

```
<script>
    jQuery('a[href*=#]:not([href=#slider-apietrzak])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') ||
            location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = jQuery(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : jQuery('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                jQuery('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 500);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

The menu is hidden, but the page does not move. I would like the menu to hide and go to a specific id at the same time.

You might go to the link: [www.apietrzak.pl](https://apietrzak.pl), when you want to see the page.

Thank for help!

Answer (score 0):

You are including jQuery in the footer of your page, but you are using it as inline script. If you look at your console, you will see that JQuery is not defined when you are trying to use it.

You should rework your script so that it will be executed only when JQuery is already present. For example (not the best way) move your inclusion to the head of the document.

Answer (score 0):

add a reference to jquery to Head:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>APIETRZAK - Rental of construction machinery, vehicle mechanics</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="images/icon/apple-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="images/icon/apple-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/icon/apple-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="images/icon/apple-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/icon/apple-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="images/icon/apple-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="images/icon/apple-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="images/icon/apple-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="images/icon/apple-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="images/icon/android-icon-192x192.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="images/icon/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="images/icon/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="images/icon/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="images/icon/manifest.json">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/icon/ms-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" charset="UTF-8" href="https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_static/css/translateelement.css">
</head>
```